# Do I need to restart tomcat?

Tags: java, servlets

My dynamic web project on eclipse creates temp file in directory which is in "WebContent" folder(so the path to temp file "abc" is "myapp/tmp/abc").

But I can't access that file at runtime. I can access it only after I refresh directory "tmp" in eclipse.
Is there any ability to access the temp files at runtime?
(I completely new to java web dev)

Update:
It seems that if I copy my project to my local Tomcat(which is not related with my IDE) or to server in the Internet - the errors disappear and everything works fine.

Comment: Your webapp shouldn't be accessing files from the filesystem

Comment: initially it wasn't obvious to me, then I realized that it can lead some security issues

Comment: your temp file is under project directory OR server directory?

Comment: i got the problem when attempting get files from project directory